# Make Perl Script to Compute Two's Complement on An 8-Bit Integer

Tags: perl

I have written a Perl script that takes an input hexadecimal value and then returns the binary equivalent. I need to sign that 8-bit integer and view the signed integer's value. This particular scenario does not seem to be covered in the Perl documentation that I have seen. The script is pasted below:

```
    #! perl
    use warnings;
    print "Enter hexidecimal number:";
    chomp ($hexNum = <STDIN>);
    print $hexNum . "\n";
    print  join "\n", map { unpack ('B*', pack ('H*',$_)) } split ':', 
    $hexNum;
```

This question is not the same as other entries (specifically [Converting hexadecimal numbers in strings to negative numbers, in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111839/converting-hexadecimal-numbers-in-strings-to-negative-numbers-in-perl/%22Converting%20hexadecimal%20numbers%20in%20strings%20to%20negative%20numbers,%20in%20Perl%22) because it deals specifically with an 8 bit integer, not simply converting to decimal.

Comment: Please show some sample input and the desired output. It's not clear to me what you mean.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate -- please see the link in [a3f](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1257035/a3f) comment.

Answer (score 4):

The two's complement of a number `$n` is just `-$n`. To limit the result to 8 bits, mask off the rest using `(-$n)&0xff`.

Comment: I need to print the result so that I can see the bits flipped. The reason for this is to configure the Tx Load for a Bluetooth Low Energy beacon. For example, I would put in 0xEE and see the 8-bit representation of -18.

Answer (score 1):

```
#Hex to Binary and check whether it is signed or unsigned. 
 print "Enter hexidecimal number:";
 chomp ($hexNum = <STDIN>);
 print $hexNum . "\n";
 my $bin_value = sprintf( "%08b", hex( $hexNum ));
 my $msb = ($bin_value & 0x080);
 if($msb){
 print "Unsigned Number\n"}
 else {
 print "Signed Number\n";}
```

In case you are converting hexadecimal to decimal in that case you need to take 2's complement for which you can use `-` operator.